# Details of Spivak's Proof of Stokes' Theorem

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

In Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, the proof of Stokes Theorem on $\mathbb{R}^n$ begins as follows...

[image: Spivak Stokes Proof]

It seems to me that there's something here which can be very confusing: When you pull back the $k-1$ form $f dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge ... \wedge dx^k$ along ${I^k}_{(i,\alpha)}$, the result is again a $k-1$ form, which should be integrated over a $(k-1)$-cube.

However, in the line below, the integral is over $[0,1]^k$. It amounts to the same  thing, since ${I^k}_{(i,\alpha)}^*(f dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge \widehat{dx^i} \wedge ... \wedge dx^k) = f(x^1, ..., x^{i-1},\alpha,x^i, ..., x^{k-1})\,dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^{k-1}$ and then

$$ \begin{aligned}& \int_{[0,1]^{k-1}}f(x^1, ..., x^{i-1},\alpha,x^i, ..., x^{k-1})\,dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^{k-1} \\ = & \int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_{[0,1]^{k-1}}f(x^1, ..., x^{i-1},\alpha,x^i, ..., x^{k-1})\,dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^{k-1}\right)dx^k \\ = & \int_{[0,1]^{k}}f(x^1, ..., x^{i-1},\alpha,x^i, ..., x^{k-1})\,dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^k \\ = & \int_{[0,1]^{k}}f(x^1, ..., x^{i-1},\alpha,x^{i}, ..., x^{k-1})\,dx^1 ... dx^k \\ = & \int_{[0,1]^{k}}f(x^1, ..., x^{i-1},\alpha,x^{i+1}, ..., x^{k})\,dx^1 ... dx^k\end{aligned}$$

where the second line follows since the pulled back form is constant with respect to $x^k$ and the last line follows since we're working with the Riemann integral over $[0,1]^k$ so we're really just renaming variables. I think it's a bit of a stretch to ask the reader to 'note' that without any further indication as to why it's true.

Spivak pulls a similar trick later on in the proof, which I noticed another [StackExchange question on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024100/proof-of-stokes-theorem-in-mathbbrn). After having run through the steps of the proof on a small example, I'm guessing that the reason for doing this is to avoid having to talk about renaming variables.

So, my two questions are:

- Is there a simpler way to make sense of the 'note' which I addressed above?
- Am I correct in thinking that the extra integration is done to make the proof more concise and avoid discussion of renaming variables? Or is there some other reason I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it's conceptually somewhat unsatisfying to turn the $(k-1)$-dimensional integrals into $k$-dimensional integrals, but it avoids all sorts of ugly notation. Note, for example, that in the second line of your second paragraph, you got it wrong: You should have written
$$(I^k_{i,\alpha}){}^*f dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k = f(x^1,\dots,x^{i-1},\alpha,x^{i+1},\dots,x^k)dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k.$$
Rewriting all the integrals over the $k$-cube avoids the notational morass. (It's not a matter of "remaining" variables; it's a matter of notating which one is omitted. But most likely that's what you intended.)

Comment: Are you sure? Following Spivak's definitions, the domain of ${I^k}_{i,\alpha}$ is $[0,1]^{k-1}$, and the pullback of $dx^k$ along that map is $dx^{k-1}$, since the map sends the $(k-1)^{th}$ coordinate of $[0,1]^{k-1}$ into the $k^th$ coordinate of $[0,1]^k$. When you're computing a particular example, you can treat the faces one at a time and just think about 'removing a variable', but the technically, the boundary of a $k$-cube is a $(k-1)$-chain defined over $[0,1]^{k-1}$, so the projection $x^k$ and the form $dx^k$ don't make sense on the right hand side of that equation.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I had to go back and look at Spivak's book. And we do have to worry about signs eventually, which he does next.

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for the affirmation. I know it's really just formalities, but I wanted to be sure that if you stick to the definitions as stated, then the calculation I posted above is (i) correct and (ii) required.